# JQuery Validation Error on textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following HTML form in an MVC 4 view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ManageAdministrator", FormMethod.Post, 
        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"id", "manageAdministratorForm"}}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("emailAddressTextbox", null,
                  new Dictionary<string, object> {{"id", "emailAddressTextbox"}})
}
```

I want to apply JQuery validation with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        $("#manageAdministratorForm").validate({
            rules: {
                emailAddressTextbox: {
                    required: true
            }
        },
        comment: "The email address is required"
    });
  });
});
```

I get the following errort when performing the validation

```
 JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by the JQuery Validation plugin that I was using. 
I updated to the  newest JQuery Validation Plugin (1.11) using Nuget and everything is now working as expected.

Hope this is helpful to someone in future.